# Как вытащить почту Google аккаунта из телефона и использовать в приложении

Tags: android, email, google-play

Возник довольно нестандартный вопрос - можно ли как-то вытащить почту вашего гугл акк из телефона. Сейчас у многих есть android смартфоны, в которых есть куча гугл приложений (play market, gmail и тд.) в которых человек чаще всего использует свой гугл аккаунт. Вот в приложении мне нужно как-то вытащить почту гугла если это реально. Я допускаю что гугл запрещает приложениям тащить эти данные но все-таки может есть способ?

Comment: Что тащим - имейл-адрес или сообщения?

Comment: а откуда сообщение тянуть то? я просто думал может можно как-то вытащить из гугл акк на телефоне адрес почты

Comment: Сообщения на гмейле доступны через стандартные протоколы чтения почты. Поэтому поддерживаю вопрос @Эникейщик

Comment: а нельзя не через почту тянуть адрес? например как-то получить доступ к акк на телефоне? или это никак нельзя по-другому сделать?

Comment: Если я правильно интерпретирую вопрос, то вам нужен доступ к аккаунтам на телефоне. Его можно запросить через разрешение [GET_ACCOUNTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#GET_ACCOUNTS).